# How to Instatiate a class with same name while autoloading a 3rd party Library with Yii Framework?

Tags: php, yii

Importing `vendor` folder **In config/main.php**:

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.vendor.*'
),
```

Add an alias (Don't know if required):

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('oauth', '/../vendor/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/src/OAuth2');
```

So according to the [Oauth documentation](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/) I use:

```
$storage = new OAuth2\Storage\Pdo(array('dsn' => $dsn, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
```

so I change it to:

```
$storage = new Pdo(array('dsn' => $dsn, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
```

But it is picking up the wrong class here. How can I make sure it is using the one from the 3rd-party library.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `import` configuration, as that won't be sufficient since Yii's autoloader doesn't work recursively. Instead, you need to take advantage of the fact that Yii supports [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) autoloading, (and that this package uses PSR-0), if you set the alias path correctly.

Add the following to your main config:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias(
    'OAuth2', 
    __DIR__.'/../vendor/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/src/OAuth2'
);
```

You MUST use the alias `OAuth2`, and not `oauth` or any other variation.

In a file that you wish to use the class, place:

```
use OAuth2\Storage\Pdo;
```

at the top of the file. At that point, you can reference the Pdo object as you did at the end of your question:

```
$storage = new Pdo(array('dsn' => $dsn, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
```

Note: the `use` statement is unnecessary if you simply directly reference the class via it's namespace, as you did in the 2nd to last code block in your question:

```
$storage = new OAuth2\Storage\Pdo(array('dsn' => $dsn, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
```